# Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, content-security-policy

I was trying to fix this error I was facing:

"Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy."

I'm trying to make a contact us page and its unable to POST.

```
import React, {useState,setState} from 'react';
import "./Contactus.css";
import axios from 'axios';

class Contactus extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''
    }
  }
  
   handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url:"http://localhost:3002/send",
      data:  this.state
    }).then((response)=>{
      if (response.data.status === 'success') {
        alert("Message Sent.");
        this.resetForm()
      } else if (response.data.status === 'fail') {
        alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
    })
  }

  resetForm(){
    this.setState({name: null, email: null, message: null})
  }
render() {
  return (
    <div className="contact-form-box">

      <h1> Contact Us</h1>
      <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
        <textarea className="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
  );
}
onNameChange(event) {
  this.setState({name: event.target.value})
}

onEmailChange(event) {
  this.setState({email: event.target.value})
}

onMessageChange(event) {
  this.setState({message: event.target.value})
}

handleSubmit(event) {
}
}

export default Contactus;
```

I have tried adding a META tag outlining the content security policy in the index.js file but it created more errors alongside the original ones

Answer (score 0):

A content security policy is already applied to your site. Adding another policy can only make it stricter. You will need to locate and modify the source of the existing policy or rewrite your page to adhere to it. Specifically you do at least need to rewrite inline event handlers (like your onSubmit) into event listeners in a separate js file. If script-src exists and includes 'self' that file will be allowed. If script-src directive is missing then default-src should include 'self' for that file to be allowed.